# Loading .csv data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was trying to load a dataset from my local computer using pandas, I put r in front of C, changed \ and tried /, when I run the code I got these problems, please anyone help me :

```
import pandas
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import csv
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import feature_select
import depmeas

if __name__=='__main__':
    NUM_CV = 3
    RANDOM_SEED = 123
    MAX_ITER = 1000

    leuk = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/pc/Desktop/dataset/leukemia.csv')
    X = leuk['data']
    y = leuk['target']

    # split the data for testing
    (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

    # perform feature selection
    num_features_to_select = 25
    K_MAX = 1000
    estimator = depmeas.mi_tau
    n_jobs = -1
    feature_ranking = feature_select.feature_select(X_train, y_train, num_features_to_select=num_features_to_select, K_MAX=K_MAX, estimator=estimator, n_jobs=n_jobs)
    num_selected_features = len(feature_ranking )
```

i search and found some answers but not related to my quesion the Errors is :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\MymrmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.enter code here`get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/MymrmrTest/feature_select_test.py", line 39, in <module>
    X = df['data']
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\MymrmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\MymrmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'data'
```

Comment: It seems like you simply don't have a `data` column in the csv... Make sure it has the right format...

Comment: Looks your data loaded fine.. in 'leuk' but the leuk doesn't have the column value as data

Comment: Just check for spaces in the column name etc.

Comment: Check the columns. `leuk.columns`

Comment: what is estimator = depmeas.mi_tau here. How can I try this. I searched on google but did not find depmeas.mi_tau. Can you explain it a little bit.